Self-adjointness for real Hilbert space
For a complex Hilbert space $H$, a bounded operator $A$ is self-adjoint iff $\langle Ah,h\rangle\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $h\in H$. But is there a simple analogous result to determine when $A$ is self-adjoint for a real Hilbert space? For finite-dim, it's just being symmetric. But what should be the appropriate formulation for inf-dim case? We can require $\langle Ax,y\rangle$ to be a bounded symmetric bilinear form. But that just seems like rephrasing the definition. Are there somewhat sophisticated results? Thanks in advance.

Its complexification is self-adjoint, maybe? Though if you write that out it’s again just saying $\langle Ax, y \rangle$ is a symmetric form.

Since you can always get skew-symmetric operators, though, there really isn’t any criteria that allow you to only consider $\langle Ax, x \rangle$.
